# JQuery Datatable plugin doesn't work correctly in CodeIgniter 3.x

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

This'll be my first time posting here.

Please forgive my little knowledge on programming. I'm fairly new to PHP with just 3 weeks of practice. I've just been working on a simple CodeIgniter 3.x project using Netbeans, for around the same time I'm practicing PHP. I'd like to output a simple datatable using the JQuery Datatable plugin from [here](http://holt59.github.io/datatable/). I think I've followed the simple 'Your first datatable' example posted there correctly. Though I don't understand why my code won't work.

Here's my index.php, which is the view:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Employee Database
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/datatable-bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">                  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/datatable.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <center>
                <h1>
                    Employee DB
                </h1>
            </center>
        </header>
    <center>    
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>               
                <th>
                    Employee Code
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employee Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employment Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Dept. Code
                </th>
                <th>
                    Dept. Description
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach ($results as $results_item): ?>        
            <tbody>
            <tr>  
                <td>
                   <?php echo $results_item['empcode']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <?php echo $results_item['empdesc']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $results_item['empdate']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $results_item['deptcode']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $results_item['deptdesc']; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
        <div id="paging-first-datatable"></div>
            <!--<?php //var_dump($results);?>-->
        </center>
    </body>    
</html>
```

here's my index.js:

```js
$('#first-datatable-output table').datatable({
    pageSize: 10,
    sort: [true, true, true, true, true],
    filters: [true, true, true, true, true],
    filterText: 'What do you wish to find?'
});
```

It doesn't seem to work. The only output I get is just a full table with nothing paginated. I console.log on my index.js javascript, to check whether I've linked them correctly, with a simple hello world and the message does output on the console as expected, the style.css seems to work too.

Any solution, response, and insight is deeply appreciated!

Thank you!!!

Okay so from the replies I got I finally managed to get it working!!

My only problem now is fixing the buttons for the pagination

They look something like this: [Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKkWV.png)

Any idea how to spruce it up?

Comment: are you getting any error related to datatables plugin?

Comment: Where is the `id="first-datatable-output"` in your html code?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors relating to the plugin on the console.


As for the id I only followed the example shown on the link so I'm not sure where to place it. Though I will try to put a div tag with the id first-datatable-output around the table and see if that'll fix it

Comment: you can give an `id` to your table and using that `id` selector can initialize datatables

Comment: I tried changing the id for the table as `id="test"` and id reference on the js file to `$(#test)` but the datatable still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The documentation does not even use the ID. I dont get why it is specified then... But he followed the docs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the table body tags IN your foreach loop, which will output the tags for each result you have. You need to place them outside of your foreach.
Change this:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $results_item): ?>        
    <tbody>
        <tr>  
            <td>
               <?php echo $results_item['empcode']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
               <?php echo $results_item['empdesc']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $results_item['empdate']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $results_item['deptcode']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $results_item['deptdesc']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

into this:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($results as $results_item): ?>        
        <tr>  
            <td>
               <?php echo $results_item['empcode']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
               <?php echo $results_item['empdesc']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $results_item['empdate']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $results_item['deptcode']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $results_item['deptdesc']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

The documentation states the tag is really important. Try this and let me know!

When reading the documentation you could also use JS directly. Maybe try that?

Try this for your index.js:

```
var datatable = new DataTable(document.querySelector('#first-datatable-output table'), {
    pageSize: 10,
    sort: [true, true, true, true, true],
    filters: [true, true, true, true, true],
    filterText: 'What do you wish to find?'
});
```

I inspected the source code of the Documentation. They put the table into a div with the id `first-datatable-output`... They do not document that anywhere.
You could try to put this `<div id="first-datatable-output">` BEFORE `<table class="table table-bordered">` and a `</div>` AFTER `<div id="paging-first-datatable"></div>`

For the pagination, try adding `class="pagination-datatables text-center"` to the `<div id="paging-first-datatable">` like `<div id="paging-first-datatable" class="pagination-datatables text-center">`.

Holy... their documentation is baaaaaaaaad!

Comment: Thanks for the correction! 

The data does appear on the table, but the only things missing now are the search boxes and the pagination which are supposed to be part of the plugin.

Comment: Corrected... Sorry i didnt read far enough. Maybe try the JS implementation first? Let me know.

Comment: Okay so I tried the js one and to my surprise a bunch of errors appears on the console. 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tHead' of null
    at new DataTable (datatable.js:28)
    at index.js:1`

Comment: Can you try adding `id="first-datatable-output"` to `<table class="table table-bordered">`? Like `<table class="table table-bordered" id="first-datatable-output">` Also see my last edit. They wrapped the tavble in an undocumented div with the right ID...

Comment: The code works! 
The page displays around 10 of the data inside, but there's no sign of the pagination.....

Comment: See my last edit please, maybe that will work? Their documentation is really really bad. Not weird you dont get it working.

Comment: I've changed the class to `class="paging"` to get it to work, the text-center doesn't change it's appearance nor its position

Comment: Thanks for the replies bro!

I've finally managed to fix everything including the button design by tweaking the css a bit and downloading the latest bootstrap, i'm extremely grateful

Comment: That is probably because you use the depracated `<center>` html tags. Use CSS instead of those tags, google is your friend. No problem at all. Good luck and i will maybe do a Pull Request on that documentation because it is really bad for new people to get this...